# Is there a way to integrate other software in a Blender pipeline?

Tags: workflow, external-applications

I'm considering starting a small studio, but the people I know do not use Blender.  Is there any known way to effectively integrate other programs into a pipeline like Maya and After Effects with Blender?  I watched Francesco Siddi's talk on Blender Pipeline, but admittedly, I found it difficult to understand.

Comment: I think this question is likely to be flagged as opinion. Can you provide a more concrete (aka answerable) example?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is a step by step approach that studios use with predominantly Blender to integrate other programs in their pipeline.  Or, is Blender pipeline only meant to be used with Blender?

Comment: I don't know that there is a single step by step approach, but the way I go about integrating tools into a work flow is to try to answer two questions: What order makes the most sense for using the programs?  (obvious example: Lightroom should go before Photoshop) What has to be done in each program to optimize moving work between them? (what format they both understand , for example.)

Comment: Yes those the questions I have for sure. Because for example, if I am working with a concept artist, it's pretty easy to import the vector or image in Blender, model it and get it textured in Substance Painter or Maya. But if I have the model made in Blender with compositing and texturing, would it work to export that to Houdini for physics? Or if you are working with many environments and objects in many different programs, how can you use it all in Blender to preview when the environment and poly count is huge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to be the supervisor of a studio where we are using Blender.
First, I implanted blender for modeling/UV, you can then export the mesh in obj or FBX and used them in any CG software (Maya, Max, etc ...)

Then we started to animate in Blender and render in 3DS Max with Vray, so all Modeling, Setup, Animation were done in Blender, then you export the all scene in Alembic, that keep animation data and you can load it in Max or Maya to make the render.

As for Compositing software, of course you can use any Blender render (use pass render in EXR) in Nuke, Fusion or After Effect.

So yes, Blender can be implented, in my humble opinion, in any pipe, and more easely if you are starting your own bussiness.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Wow thanks that excellent to know that it can work! So from what I gather Blender files, compositing and animation data can be seamlessly integrated into other programs? But can other programs export to Blender as well?

Comment: Any programs that can export to blender-readable file types work. Like .obj, .fbx, alembic files, and any image files. So, in other words, it depends on the program and what you're using it for. But most likely, yes